# Python, Dask - Using functions from another module and mapping to Dask Dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dask, dask-dataframe

I am trying to apply a bunch of functions on a dask data frame using map_partitions. It works when the function is defined locally eg:

```
#assume a data frame df1

def upper(x):
    return x.str.upper()

def process(df,info): 
    for mapper,col in info['process']:
        df[col] = df[col].map_partitions(mapper, meta=df[col])
    return df

info = {'process':[(upper, 'column_name')]}
df = process(df1, info)

df.head()
```

but when we split the code into modules it does not work..

helper.py

```
def upper(x):
    return x.str.upper()

def upper_lambda():
    return lambda x: x.str.upper()
```

main.py

```
import helper

#assume a data frame df1

def process(df,info): 
    for mapper,col in info['process']:
        df[col] = df[col].map_partitions(mapper, meta=df[col])
    return df

info = {'process':[(getattr(helper,'upper'), 'column_name')]}
#Tried with the lambda too.. dosent seem to work 
#info = {'process':[(helper.upper(), 'column_name')]}

df = process(df1, info)

df.head()
```

It just throws back KilledWorker:("('assign-read-parquet-head-1-5-assign-77bd7b855e5e8eec82312c65361fc7c5', 0)",

Comment: Any logs from the worker? It would be good to show how the file is made and loaded, as simple as possible.

Comment: I recommend providing an MCVE, https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dask certainly supports using functions from another module.  However, those modules are expected to exist on all machines that you're using.

For small files like your `helper.py` file you may want to look into `Client.upload_file` to help you move it around.